How to start chrome remote debug with python in windows system
I am using chrome remote debug with selenium to do some experiment, the chrome remote debug works as follow:
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

And then, I use selenium Chrome webdriver to collect information on some website, but I find that the python program does not run steady in the mode of chrome remote debugging  as it works in the mode of selenium/standalone-firefox, the program often suddenly stops and I have to start the chrome remote debug manually, so I appreciate someone who can give me advice to finish a python program with automatically start chrome remote debugging and my selenium program

It's very difficult to help without more details. If you will update your question following this guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, I could try to have a look

@xoxouser, I finally solve this problem by annotating the code "driver.close();driver.quit()", thus the debug chrome browser will not be closed, thanks for your reply
